# Canonical link or block in robots.txt for duplicate content across domains?

Tags: duplicate-content, robots.txt, canonical-url

I've built a WordPress multisite for a dealership which has different franchises, ie Honda and BMW. Each franchise has its own website which have a used section, with identical content on them all for used stock.

Am I best using a canonical link to tell the search engines its duped content from one of the multisite sites, or am I best blocking the pages for the used stock in robots.txt for all sites other than the main dealer one?

I've read arguments for and against both approaches, what does the wider development community feel is the best approach?

Comment: I would think from a users point of view, a canonical link is best. As well, you might get a slightly better penetration in the SERPs- who knows. As a user, I am not sure I would appreciate a redirect. However, if the used section only existed on one site and the "used" link/button took me to another site, that would be acceptable and may be your best bet.